# Syntax message given when i submit a def command

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial from my internal work training (similar to online school),and there is this project that tells you to write some code following the instructions on the videos given, and there is one that gives me a syntax error but, since I'm am very new to programming I don't understand why is it, I've used different combinations but no success.

I'm learning Python 3 IDE to write the code

Code:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 1
        self.name = "Bot1"
        print (self.name, "has been created ", ", age", self.age)

    def talk (self, words = ("I dont know what to say :("))
        print self.name, ":", words

Bot1 = Bot()
Bot1.talk()
Bot1.talk("Hello, im talking")
```

This is the error message I received:

```
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 7
   def talk (self, words = ("I dont know what to say :("))
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
"
```

Comment: Python code needs to be properly indented or it will not work. A `def` line needs a colon at the end. The arguments to `print` need to be in parentheses.

Comment: You are missing a colon `:` at the end of your function signature

Comment: You really should check out a basic online Python tutorial or text book before attempting to write Python code. An IDE isn't in and of itself a learning tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a colon at the end of line 7.

Note: Then every line in the function should be indented.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing a colon `:` at the end of your function signature, and is also lacking indentation (which is required in Python). The corrected code is as below-

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 1
        self.name = "Bot1"
        print (self.name, "has been created ", ", age", self.age)

    def talk (self, words = ("I dont know what to say :(")):
        print self.name, ":", words

Bot1 = Bot()
Bot1.talk()
Bot1.talk("Hello, im talking")
```

Comment: I appreciate all your help, i was able to make it work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
    self.age = 1
    self.name = "Bot1"
    print (self.name, "has been created ", ", age", self.age)

    # This should have been indented to be inside of the class
    # You didn't need brackets around your "words" parameter.
    def talk(self, words="I dont know what to say :("): # You needed a semi-colon here
        print(self.name, ":", words) # You needed to add brackets here.

Bot1 = Bot()
Bot1.talk()
Bot1.talk("Hello, im talking")
```